# Does quantum immortality mean solipsism?

Tags: quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations, solipsism, multiverse, immortality

If when we die another universe is created in which we live, then would the people of that universe be real?( by that i mean conscious beings like myself) or am I misunderstanding QI?

Comment: Why do you ponder if the people in the parallel worlds under the multiple-worlds interpretation of quantum physics would be “philosophical zombies”? That is, without consciousness? Your question is confusing (to me) because I don’t grasp it’s motivation.

Comment: Hokon, if when I die i create a different reality, if I leave all tye people behind than is the new reality full of concious beings ie are the people I know and love real? It seems kinda solipstic so I was just wondering cause it's kinda stressing me out.

Comment: Ah I see now, thank you for the clarification. We do have a user here with a PhD in quantum physics, so hopefully he’ll answer, but from what I know “both” worlds where you died and are still alive have fully conscious, fully functioning people.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you replying and this made me feel better.

Comment: You’re welcome! If it helps you feel any better, each “you” in these worlds is equally original to the old “you.” Same applies to all your loved ones across these worlds IIRC.